# Facebook SDK v3.0 Request Dialog not sending application request

Tags: android, facebook

I am using Android SDK v3.0 for Facebook to send requests to friends for using my app. I've used the code I saw on [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/send-requests/) to open up Facebook's Dialog app and make a request to the user's friends.

After using the following code to display and send the request. I now get a "Request Sent" toast but the request is never sent.

```
private void sendRequestDialog() {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("message", "MESSAGE");
    params.putString("app_id", "APPID");

    WebDialog requestsDialog = (
        new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(LoginActivity.this,
            Session.getActiveSession(),
            params))
            .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                    FacebookException error) {
                    if (error != null) {
                        if (error instanceof FacebookException) {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), 
                                "Request cancelled", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), 
                                "Network Error", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        final String requestId = values.getString("request");
                        if (requestId != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), 
                                "Request sent",  
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), 
                                "Request cancelled", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }   
                }

            })
            .build();
    requestsDialog.show();
}
```

The following log is obtained from Logcat during the display of Request Dialog :

```
03-15 17:18:51.944: W/dalvikvm(2842): disableGcForExternalAlloc: false
03-15 17:18:53.759: V/chromium(2842): external/chromium/net/base/bandwidth_metrics.h:96: [0315/171853:INFO:bandwidth_metrics.h(96)] Bandwidth: 1500.13Kbps (avg 2275.13Kbps)
03-15 17:18:54.124: W/dalvikvm(2842): disableGcForExternalAlloc: false
03-15 17:18:58.019: W/dalvikvm(2842): disableGcForExternalAlloc: true
03-15 17:18:58.629: W/dalvikvm(2842): disableGcForExternalAlloc: false
03-15 17:18:58.684: W/dalvikvm(2842): disableGcForExternalAlloc: true
03-15 17:18:59.314: W/dalvikvm(2842): disableGcForExternalAlloc: false
03-15 17:18:59.369: W/dalvikvm(2842): disableGcForExternalAlloc: true
03-15 17:18:59.949: W/dalvikvm(2842): disableGcForExternalAlloc: false
03-15 17:18:59.954: W/dalvikvm(2842): disableGcForExternalAlloc: true
03-15 17:19:00.534: W/dalvikvm(2842): disableGcForExternalAlloc: false
03-15 17:19:00.539: W/dalvikvm(2842): disableGcForExternalAlloc: true
03-15 17:19:01.329: W/dalvikvm(2842): disableGcForExternalAlloc: false
03-15 17:19:03.459: W/dalvikvm(2842): disableGcForExternalAlloc: true
03-15 17:19:03.984: W/dalvikvm(2842): disableGcForExternalAlloc: false
03-15 17:19:04.019: W/dalvikvm(2842): disableGcForExternalAlloc: true
03-15 17:19:04.189: W/dalvikvm(2842): disableGcForExternalAlloc: false
03-15 17:19:06.269: W/dalvikvm(2842): disableGcForExternalAlloc: false
03-15 17:19:10.869: I/NONPRIME(2842): <CallBackProxy> Send to WebViewClient.
```

Please point me in the right direction...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this Facebook [developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/requests/#user_to_user) page:
"User to User Requests are only available for Canvas apps"

Answer (score 0):

In app setting in facebook developer account add a canvas framework and after that add below code to send app request.
if in activity replace getActivity() with YourActivityName.this
if in fragment no need to replace anything

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("message",
                    "Join CConnect To feel Better Experience Of Meetings And Calls");

            WebDialog requestsDialog = (new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(
                    getActivity(), Session.getActiveSession(), params))
                    .setTheme(
                            android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen))
                    .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                                FacebookException error) {
                            if (error != null) {
                                if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            getActivity()
                                                    .getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Request cancelled",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            getActivity()
                                                    .getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                            .show();
                                }
                            } else {
                                final String requestId = values
                                        .getString("request");
                                if (requestId != null) {
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            getActivity()
                                                    .getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Request sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                            .show();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            getActivity()
                                                    .getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Request cancelled",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }).build();
            requestsDialog.show();
```

Comment: is there any special settings that should be set when I add the Facebook canvas platform? I just put something to the Canvas URL, nothing more. It is not working for me

Comment: First you have to send app for review to facebook, Then you will get access to your friend list, then with the use of taggable friend api share your app link with url and tag those friend which you want. Invitable friend api only works for game api.

Comment: This is confusing. The sendRequest dialog already opens the friend list and I an choose friends who I want to send the request to. So i basically already accessed my friend list, I just cannot send the request while the toast "Request sent" shows up. Is this normal?

Comment: yes request send means request is sent, You can see it in profile of user which you had sent request. Just add canvas framework in setting of facebook . but this is used for games app because it will as canvas redirect url just add the dummy url(say your website urls). and check again app request , this is just to check if app req is working fine or not. But other then game app if you want this feature , it is not possible, You can only tag you friend whom you want your app stories to be seen.

Comment: Does this mean that for an application (which is not a game) inviting friend from facebook is impossible? I created the canvas framework (when I can add additional platforms in Settings), but if I send the request then even if the request arrives it will link to the canvas and not an arbitrary URL specified by me? So how exactly can you make an "invite friends" feature? :)

Comment: Yes exactly, we could just play a fun here , Post a status with our app link to our profile and tag friends using taggable friends api. they will see notification in their notification.